# Memory issue establishing connection to IoT Hub via DeviceClient

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

I've created a simple test app that tries to open a connection to iot hub that doesn't exists with a custom 15 seconds retry policy. After 3 minutes, it's gone through all of my 32gb memory.

The same issue occurs when it has established a connection, but then i disable the device in iot hub and it's attempting to reconnect, again it will chew up all of my memory.

I must be doing something wrong.

HELP Please!

Using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.41.3

Target Framework .Net 6

```
Console.WriteLine("Validating IoT Hub");

DeviceClient? deviceClient;

try
{
    var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey("81ebefd6-f76c-4562-b395-e3247e97d227", "rI3sxcIgDFeMqpRwSutjZ/PoZ1KX5iTUT0OnL7R44Mg=");

    deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create("asdfasdf.azure-devices.net", auth, TransportType.Mqtt);

    deviceClient.OperationTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000;
    deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler(MqttConnectionChanged);
    deviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(new CustomRetryPolicy());
    //deviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(new NoRetry());
    deviceClient.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

void MqttConnectionChanged(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason)
{
    if (status != ConnectionStatus.Connected && deviceClient != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection to IoT Hub is down! Reason: " + reason.ToString());
        deviceClient.CloseAsync();
        deviceClient.DisposeAsync();
        deviceClient = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection to IoT Hub is " + status.ToString() + ". Reason: " + reason.ToString());
    }
}
```

CustomRetryPolicy.cs

```
    public class CustomRetryPolicy : IRetryPolicy
    {
        public bool ShouldRetry(int currentRetryCount, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval)
        {
            retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Setting to no retry policy helps fix the issue

Comment: I can reproduce your issue, would you be open to add a bug report on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues)?

Comment: Will do. It doesn't seem to have the issue in version 2

Answer (score 0):

> using ExponentialBackoff I created a custom 15 seconds retry policy.
> I used the version
> -Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.41.3
> Framework  - Target Framework .Net 6.

```cs
deviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoff(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.Ft romSeconds(3)));
```

```cs
deviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoff(retryCount, minBackoff, maxBackoff, deltaBackoff));
```

> I followed the below steps to connect to IoT Hub.

- I created a [IoT device](https://www.winccoa.com/documentation/WinCCOA/latest/en_US/Treiber_MQTT/mqtt_azure_broker/topics/mqtt_azurebroker_create_iothub_and_device.html#:%7E:text=Create%20an%20Iot%20hub%20and%20a%20device%201,to%20the%20Review%20+%20create%20tab:%20More%20items)

[image]

-In visual studio enter the below code.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;

namespace IoTHubConnectionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string IotHubUri = "YOUR IotHubUri";
        private const string DeviceId = "YOUR DeviceId";
        private const string DeviceKey = "YOUR DeviceKey";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to IoT Hub...");

            DeviceClient deviceClient = null;
            try
            {
                var authMethod = new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey);
                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IotHubUri, authMethod, TransportType.Mqtt);
                deviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoff(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)));
                deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatusChangesHandler);

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to IoT Hub!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error connecting to IoT Hub: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

            if (deviceClient != null)
            {
                deviceClient.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection status changed to {status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Reason: {reason}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- Replace the [IotHubUri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc6Bp.png), [DeviceId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcmEV.png) , [DeviceKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/monhT.png) and run the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think this solves the issue or answers my question. My problem is not getting it working, but rather it chewing up alot of memory when it's not connected, which could happen when you lose connection to the IoT device.

Comment: In terms of memory consumption, the `IoTHubClient` library works with default behaviour, but there are a few options that you can set to change how the library works, for more information check this [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-dps/concepts-deploy-at-scale.md)